# Compatibility issue with Chrome/Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, dreamweaver

My site is available at: http://www.innexdesign.co.uk/dev . The site works perfectly in IE and most pages are also fine in Firefox and Chrome. 
However if we navigate to the "Designs" Menu and hover down the choices: "Designs for Drinking", "Designs for Eating" etc you see the logo and fitter divs appear to move a bit further down as you hover over them.
Similarly if you were to select "Designs for drinking" and hover over the individual pubs you would again see the logo and footer divs appear to move down the page as you hover over them. This also happens in "Designs for Eating", "Designs for Housing" and "Designs for Sleeping".

I assume you guys can see all the code just by visiing the site but i'll paste some below incase that is not possible:

styles.css:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: shruti;
   src: url(‘shruti.ttf’);
}

html, body, div, ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color : #040404;
    background-image : url(images/bk.jpg);
    background-position : top;
    background-repeat : repeat-x;
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
    font-family : shruti, Arial, Geneva;
    font-size : 90%;
    line-height:100%;
}
p {
    font-family : shruti, Arial, Geneva;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size : 100%;
    line-height:normal;
    padding: 5px;
}
h1 {
    font-size : 24px;
    padding-bottom:10px;    
}

h2 {
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
ul {
    list-style : none;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
}
a:link {
    color : #000;
    text-decoration : none;
    color : #000;
}
a:active {
    font-style : italic;
    color : #000;
}
a:visited {
    font-style : italic;
    color : #00C;
}
a {
    outline: none;
}

a img {
    vertical-align: top;


}

a img.last {
    margin-right: 0;    
}

img {
    border : none;
}
#wrapper {
    width : 994px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    background-color : #e3d9b9;
}
#header {
    width : 994px;
    height : 483px;
    margin : 0 auto;
}
#page {
    width : 994px;
    position : relative;
    background-image : url(images/page_bk.jpg);
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-position : top;
    background-color : #b08f40;
}
#pageheader {
    width : 100%;
    height : 220px;
    position : relative;
    background-image : url(images/header_bk.png);
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-position : top;
}
#logo {
width : 143px;
height : 206px;
position : relative;
padding : 10px 10px 0 10px;
float : left;
}
#social {
float : left;
padding : 10px 10px 0 10px;
}
#content {
    width : 994px;
    min-height:200px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    padding : 0;
    background-image : url(images/homepage_bk.jpg);
    background-position : top;
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-color : #b08f40;
    overflow:auto;
}
#logosother {
    height: 160px;
    width: 994px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #e3d9b9;
    background-image: url(images/top_footer.jpg);
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    clear:both;

}
.logos {
    height:52px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:82px;
    background-color : #e3d9b9;
}
.carbon {
    height:90px;
    width: 159px;
    padding: 10px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:42px;
    background-color : #e3d9b9;
}
.googleplus {
    width:50px;
    height:32px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top:98px;
    margin-left:130px;  
    float:left;
}
.homelogos {
    height:52px;
    width: 974px;   
    padding: 10px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:52px;
    background-color : #e3d9b9; 
}
#pagecontent {
    width : 100%;
    padding : 0;
    overflow : auto;
}
#left {
    width : 200px;
    float : left;
}
#homeleft {
    width : 200px;
    float : left;
}
.menu {
    margin-left : 10px;
    margin-top : 20px;
    margin-bottom : 10px;
}
.menu li {
    border-bottom : 1px solid #f9f5e7;
    border-top : 1px solid #a79c78;
    padding-bottom : 5px;
    padding-top : 5px;
    padding-left : 10px;
}
.menu li a {
    font-size : 18px;
    color : #000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    font-weight : bold;
    font-style : italic;
    color : #000;
}
.menu li a:active {
    font-weight : bold;
    font-style : italic;
    color : #000;
}
.menu li a:visited {
    font-weight : bold;
    font-style : italic;
    color : #000;
}
.menu .first {
    border-top : none;
}
.menu .last {
    border-bottom : none;
}
#homeright {
    width : 700px;
    margin-left : 20px;
    float : left;
    padding-top : 20px;
    overflow:auto;

}
#right {
    width : 700px;
    margin-left : 20px;
    float : left;
    font-size : 14px;
    font-weight : normal;
    line-height : normal;
    padding-top : 20px;
}
#newright {
width : 730px;
min-height:300px;
float : left;
font-size : 14px;
font-weight : bold;
line-height : 135%;
margin-left : 30px;
padding-top : 20px;
}
.service_menu {
width : 190px;
float:left;
}
.service_menu li {
padding : 8px 0;
width:180px;
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
.service_menu li a {
font-size : 14px;
color : #000;
}
.service_menu li a:hover {
font-weight : bold;
font-style : italic;
color : #000;
}
.service_menu li a:active {
font-weight : bold;
font-style : italic;
color : #000;
}
.service_menu li a:visited {
color : #000;
}
.service_menu .first {
border-top : none;
}
.service_menu .last {
border-bottom : none;
}
.serv {
    min-height:300px;
}
.des3 {
float : left;
width : 300px;
margin-left:20px;
}
.desimg3 {
float : left;
width : 340px;
}
#footer {
    width : 984px;
    height : 40px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    font-size : 12px;
    padding : 5px;
    clear : both;
    background-image : url(images/footer_bk.jpg);
    background-repeat : repeat-x;
    color: #000;
}

.msg_list {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
width : 670px;
float : left;
}
.msg_head {
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
background-image : url(images/expand_bk.png);
background-repeat : repeat-x;
height : 29px;
line-height : 29px;
color : #000;
margin : 1px;
font-size : 12px;
padding-left : 10px;
}
.msg_head :hover {
padding : 5px 10px;
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
background-color : #fff;
color : #fff;
margin : 1px;
font-size : 16px;
}
.msg_body {
overflow : auto;
padding : 10px 10px;
}
.msg_body p {
font-size : 12px;
line-height : 150%;
font-weight : normal;
}
.des {
float : left;
width : 300px;
padding-right:10px;
}
.desimg {
float : left;
width : 340px;
}

.msg_list1 {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
width : 300px;
float : left;
}
.msg_head1 {
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
height : 31px;
}
.msg_head1 :hover {
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
}
.msg_body1 {
overflow : auto;
padding : 0 10px;
}
.msg_body1 p {
font-size : 12px;
line-height : 150%;
font-weight : normal;
}
.des1 {
float : left;
width : 300px;
margin-right : 10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-top:10px;
}

.desimg1 {
float : left;
width : 340px;
}

.newdes {
float : left;
width : 340px;
margin-right : 10px;
}
.msg_list2 {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
width : 360px;
float : left;
}
.msg_head2 {
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
background-image : url(images/expand_bk.png);
background-repeat : repeat-x;
height : 31px;
line-height : 31px;
color : #000;
margin : 1px;
font-size : 12px;
padding-left : 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 5px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}
.msg_head2 :hover {
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
margin : 1px;
}
.msg_body2 {
overflow : auto;
padding : 0 10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
.msg_body2 p {
font-size : 12px;
line-height : 150%;
font-weight : normal;
padding:0px;
}
.newdes2 {
float : left;
width : 340px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
.desimg2 {
float : left;
width : 340px;
}


.servintro {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
width : 700px;
overflow : auto;
}
.servintrotext {
float : left;
width : 270px;
padding : 0 10px 10px 10px;
}
.servintroimg {
float : left;
width : 340px;
}
#slider {
width : 994px;
height : 483px;
margin-bottom : 10px;
margin-left : auto;
margin-right : auto;
}
#slider ul, #slider li {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
list-style : none;
}
#slider li {
width : 994px;
height : 483px;
overflow : hidden;
}
.headerimg {
background-position : center top;
background-repeat : no-repeat;
width : 994px;
height : 483px;
position : absolute;
}
.testimonial {
border : 1px solid #000;
padding : 10px;
margin-bottom : 10px;
margin-top : 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}
.office {
border : 1px solid #000;
padding : 10px;
margin-bottom : 10px;
margin-top : 10px;
width:100%;
height:265px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}
* {
padding : 0;
}
#TB_window {
font : 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color : #333333;
}
#TB_secondLine {
font : 10px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color : #666666;
}
#TB_window a:link {
color : #666666;
}
#TB_window a:visited {
color : #666666;
}
#TB_window a:hover {
color : #000;
}
#TB_window a:active {
color : #666666;
}
#TB_window a:focus {
color : #666666;
}
#TB_overlay {
position : fixed;
z-index : 100;
top : 0;
left : 0;
height : 100%;
width : 100%;
}
.TB_overlayMacFFBGHack {
background : url(macFFBgHack.png) repeat;
}
.TB_overlayBG {
background-color : #000;
}
* html #TB_overlay {
position : absolute;
}
#TB_window {
position : fixed;
background : #ffffff;
z-index : 102;
color : #000000;
display : none;
border : 4px solid #525252;
text-align : left;
top : 50%;
left : 50%;
}
* html #TB_window {
position : absolute;
}
#TB_window img#TB_Image {
display : block;
margin : 15px 0 0 15px;
border-right : 1px solid #ccc;
border-bottom : 1px solid #ccc;
border-top : 1px solid #666;
border-left : 1px solid #666;
}
#TB_caption {
height : 25px;
padding : 7px 30px 10px 25px;
float : left;
}
#TB_closeWindow {
height : 25px;
padding : 11px 25px 10px 0;
float : right;
}
#TB_closeAjaxWindow {
padding : 7px 10px 5px 0;
margin-bottom : 1px;
text-align : right;
float : right;
}
#TB_ajaxWindowTitle {
float : left;
padding : 7px 0 5px 10px;
margin-bottom : 1px;
}
#TB_title {
background-color : #e8e8e8;
height : 27px;
}
#TB_ajaxContent {
clear : both;
padding : 2px 15px 15px 15px;
overflow : auto;
text-align : left;
line-height : 1.4em;
}
#TB_ajaxContent.TB_modal {
padding : 15px;
}
#TB_ajaxContent p {
padding : 5px 0 5px 0;
}
#TB_load {
position : fixed;
display : none;
height : 13px;
width : 208px;
z-index : 103;
top : 50%;
left : 50%;
margin : -6px 0 0 -104px;
}
* html #TB_load {
position : absolute;
}
#TB_HideSelect {
z-index : 99;
position : fixed;
top : 0;
left : 0;
background-color : #fff;
border : none;
height : 100%;
width : 100%;
}
* html #TB_HideSelect {
position : absolute;
}
#TB_iframeContent {
clear : both;
border : none;
margin-bottom : -1px;
margin-top : 1px;
}
hr {
    border: none;
    height: 1px; line-height: 1px;
    background: #E5E5E5;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}

.designimage {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
    border:solid 2px #000;  
}
.designlogo {
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left; 
}
.mapleft {
    float:left;
    width:220px;
}
.mapcenter {
    float:left;
    width:260px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.mapright {
    float:left;
    width:220px;
}
```

all-ie-only.css

```
# font-face {
   font-family: shruti;
   src: url(‘shruti.ttf’);
}

html, body, div, ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color : #040404;
    background-image : url(images/bk.jpg);
    background-position : top;
    background-repeat : repeat-x;
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
    font-family : shruti, Arial, Geneva;
    font-size : 90%;
    line-height:150%;   
}
p {
    font-family : shruti, Arial, Geneva;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size : 90%;
    line-height:150%;
    padding: 5px;
}
h1 {
    font-size : 24px;
    padding-bottom:10px;    
}

h2 {
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
ul {
    list-style : none;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
}
a:link {
    color : #000;
    text-decoration : none;
    color : #000;
}
a:active {
    color : #000;
}
a:visited {
    color : #000;
}
a {
    outline: none;
}

a img {
    vertical-align: top;
}

a img.last {
    margin-right: 0;    
}

img {
    border : none;
}
#wrapper {
    width : 994px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    background-color : #e3d9b9;
}
#header {
    width : 994px;
    height : 483px;
    margin : 0 auto;
}
#page {
    width : 994px;
    position : relative;
    background-image : url(images/page_bk.jpg);
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-position : top;
    background-color : #b08f40;
}
#pageheader {
width : 100%;
height : 248px;
position : relative;
background-image : url(images/header_bk.png);
background-repeat : no-repeat;
background-position : top;
}
#logo {
width : 143px;
height : 206px;
position : relative;
padding : 10px 10px 0 10px;
float : left;
}
#social {
float : left;
padding : 10px 10px 0 10px;
}
#content {
    width : 994px;
    min-height:200px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    padding : 0;
    background-image : url(images/homepage_bk.jpg);
    background-position : top;
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-color : #b08f40;
    overflow:auto;
}
#logosother {
    height: 160px;
    width: 994px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #e3d9b9;
    background-image: url(images/top_footer.jpg);
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    clear:both;
}
.logos {
    height:52px;
    padding: 12px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:82px;
    background-color : #e3d9b9; 
}
.carbon {
    height:90px;
    width: 159px;   
    padding: 10px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:42px;
    background-color : #e3d9b9; 
}
.googleplus {
    width:50px;
    height:32px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top:92px;
    margin-left:210px;  
    float:left;
}
.homelogos {
    height:52px;
    width: 974px;   
    padding: 10px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:52px;
    background-color : #e3d9b9; 
}
#pagecontent {
    width : 100%;
    padding : 0;
    overflow : auto;
}
#left {
    width : 200px;
    float : left;
}
#homeleft {
    width : 200px;
    float : left;
}
.menu {
    margin-left : 10px;
    margin-top : 20px;
    margin-bottom : 10px;
}
.menu li {
    border-bottom : 1px solid #f9f5e7;
    border-top : 1px solid #a79c78;
    padding-bottom : 5px;
    padding-top : 5px;
    padding-left : 10px;
}
.menu li a {
    font-size : 18px;
    color : #000;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    font-weight : bold;
    font-style : italic;
    color : #000;
    text-decoration:none;   
}
.menu li a:active {
    font-weight : bold;
    color : #000;
    text-decoration:none;   
}
.menu li a:visited {
    font-weight : bold;
    color : #000;
    text-decoration:none;   
}
.menu .first {
    border-top : none;
}
.menu .last {
    border-bottom : none;
}
#homeright {
    width : 700px;
    margin-left : 20px;
    float : left;
    padding-top : 20px;
    overflow:auto;

}
#right {
    width : 700px;
    padding-left : 20px;
    float : left;
    font-size : 14px;
    font-weight : bold;
    line-height : 135%;
    padding-top : 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#newright {
    width : 700px;
    padding-left : 20px;
    float : left;
    font-size : 14px;
    font-weight : bold;
    line-height : 135%;
    padding-top : 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.service_menu {
width : 190px;
float:left;
}
.service_menu li {
padding : 8px 0;
width:180px;
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
.service_menu li a {
font-size : 14px;
color : #000;
}
.service_menu li a:hover {
font-weight : bold;
font-style : italic;
color : #000;
}
.service_menu li a:active {
font-weight : bold;
font-style : italic;
color : #000;
}
.service_menu li a:visited {
color : #000;
}
.service_menu .first {
border-top : none;
}
.service_menu .last {
border-bottom : none;
}
.serv {
    min-height:300px;
}
.des3 {
float : left;
width : 300px;
margin-left:20px;
}
.desimg3 {
float : left;
width : 340px;
}
#footer {
    width : 984px;
    height : 40px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    font-size : 12px;
    padding : 5px;
    clear : both;
    background-image : url(images/footer_bk.jpg);
    background-repeat : repeat-x;
}

.msg_list {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
width : 670px;
float : left;
}
.msg_head {
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
background-image : url(images/expand_bk.png);
background-repeat : repeat-x;
height : 29px;
line-height : 29px;
color : #000;
margin : 1px;
font-size : 12px;
padding-left : 10px;
}
.msg_head :hover {
padding : 5px 10px;
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
background-color : #fff;
color : #fff;
margin : 1px;
font-size : 16px;
}
.msg_body {
overflow : auto;
padding : 10px 10px;
}
.msg_body p {
font-size : 12px;
line-height : 150%;
font-weight : normal;
}
.des {
float : left;
width : 300px;
padding-right:10px;
}
.desimg {
float : left;
width : 340px;
}

.msg_list1 {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
width : 300px;
float : left;
}
.msg_head1 {
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
height : 31px;
}
.msg_head1 :hover {
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
}
.msg_body1 {
overflow : auto;
padding : 0 10px;
}
.msg_body1 p {
font-size : 12px;
line-height : 150%;
font-weight : normal;
}
.des1 {
float : left;
width : 300px;
margin-right : 10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-top:10px;
}

.desimg1 {
float : left;
width : 340px;
}

.newdes {
float : left;
width : 340px;
margin-right : 10px;
}
.msg_list2 {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
width : 360px;
float : left;
}
.msg_head2 {
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
background-image : url(images/expand_bk.png);
background-repeat : repeat-x;
height : 31px;
line-height : 31px;
color : #000;
margin : 1px;
font-size : 12px;
padding-left : 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 5px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}
.msg_head2 :hover {
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
margin : 1px;
}
.msg_body2 {
overflow : auto;
padding : 0 10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
.msg_body2 p {
font-size : 12px;
line-height : 150%;
font-weight : normal;
padding:0px;
}
.newdes2 {
float : left;
width : 340px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
.desimg2 {
float : left;
width : 340px;
}


.servintro {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
width : 700px;
overflow : auto;
}
.servintrotext {
float : left;
width : 270px;
padding : 0 10px 10px 10px;
}
.servintroimg {
float : left;
width : 340px;
}
#slider {
width : 994px;
height : 483px;
margin-bottom : 10px;
margin-left : auto;
margin-right : auto;
}
#slider ul, #slider li {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
list-style : none;
}
#slider li {
width : 994px;
height : 483px;
overflow : hidden;
}
.headerimg {
background-position : center top;
background-repeat : no-repeat;
width : 994px;
height : 483px;
position : absolute;
}
.testimonial {
border : 1px solid #000;
padding : 10px;
margin-bottom : 10px;
margin-top : 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}
.office {
border : 1px solid #000;
padding : 10px;
margin-bottom : 10px;
margin-top : 10px;
width:100%;
height:265px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}
* {
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
}
#TB_window {
font : 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color : #333333;
}
#TB_secondLine {
font : 10px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color : #666666;
}
#TB_window a:link {
color : #666666;
}
#TB_window a:visited {
color : #666666;
}
#TB_window a:hover {
color : #000;
}
#TB_window a:active {
color : #666666;
}
#TB_window a:focus {
color : #666666;
}
#TB_overlay {
position : fixed;
z-index : 100;
top : 0;
left : 0;
height : 100%;
width : 100%;
}
.TB_overlayMacFFBGHack {
background : url(macFFBgHack.png) repeat;
}
.TB_overlayBG {
background-color : #000;
}
* html #TB_overlay {
position : absolute;
}
#TB_window {
position : fixed;
background : #ffffff;
z-index : 102;
color : #000000;
display : none;
border : 4px solid #525252;
text-align : left;
top : 50%;
left : 50%;
}
* html #TB_window {
position : absolute;
}
#TB_window img#TB_Image {
display : block;
margin : 15px 0 0 15px;
border-right : 1px solid #ccc;
border-bottom : 1px solid #ccc;
border-top : 1px solid #666;
border-left : 1px solid #666;
}
#TB_caption {
height : 25px;
padding : 7px 30px 10px 25px;
float : left;
}
#TB_closeWindow {
height : 25px;
padding : 11px 25px 10px 0;
float : right;
}
#TB_closeAjaxWindow {
padding : 7px 10px 5px 0;
margin-bottom : 1px;
text-align : right;
float : right;
}
#TB_ajaxWindowTitle {
float : left;
padding : 7px 0 5px 10px;
margin-bottom : 1px;
}
#TB_title {
background-color : #e8e8e8;
height : 27px;
}
#TB_ajaxContent {
clear : both;
padding : 2px 15px 15px 15px;
overflow : auto;
text-align : left;
line-height : 1.4em;
}
#TB_ajaxContent.TB_modal {
padding : 15px;
}
#TB_ajaxContent p {
padding : 5px 0 5px 0;
}
#TB_load {
position : fixed;
display : none;
height : 13px;
width : 208px;
z-index : 103;
top : 50%;
left : 50%;
margin : -6px 0 0 -104px;
}
* html #TB_load {
position : absolute;
}
#TB_HideSelect {
z-index : 99;
position : fixed;
top : 0;
left : 0;
background-color : #fff;
border : none;
height : 100%;
width : 100%;
}
* html #TB_HideSelect {
position : absolute;
}
#TB_iframeContent {
clear : both;
border : none;
margin-bottom : -1px;
margin-top : 1px;
}
hr {
    border: none;
    height: 1px; line-height: 1px;
    background: #E5E5E5;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}

.designimage {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
    border:solid 2px #000;  
}
.mapleft {
    float:left;
    width:220px;
}
.mapcenter {
    float:left;
    width:260px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.mapright {
    float:left;
    width:220px;
    margin-top:180px;
}
```

My designs page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Innex Design | Services</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easySlider1.5.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $(".slider").easySlider({
                auto: true,
                continuous: true 
            });
        }); 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="page">
<div id="pageheader">
    <div id="logo"> <a href="index.html" target="_self"><img src="images/innexdesign_logo.jpg" width="143" height="206" alt="Innex Design Logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="social">
        <a href="http://twitter.com/#!/InnexDesign" target="_new"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="41" height="40" alt="Innex Design on Twitter" /></a>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/innexdesignltd" target="_new"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="41" height="40" alt="Innex Design on Facebook" /></a>
         <a href="contactform.html" title="Request a Callback" target="_new"><img src="images/callback.png" alt="" width="77" height="40" /></a>
        <a href="contactform.html" title="Leave Your Details and Sign up to our News Letter" target="_new"><img src="images/Newsletter Image.png" alt="" width="77" height="40" /></a></div>
    </div>

<div id="pagecontent">

    <div id="left">
    <ul class="menu">
    <li class="first"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.html">PROFILE</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">DESIGNS</a></li>
    <li><a href="testimonials.html">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>    
    <li class="last"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>

    <p style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">CELEBRATING<br /><span style="font-size:22px">21</span><br />YEARS<br />1991-2012</p>
    </div>

    <div id="right">

        <h1>DESIGNS</h1>

        <div class="service_menu">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="drinking.html">Designs for Drinking</a></li>
        <li><a href="eating.html">Designs for Eati
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding some line-height to the links could fix it:

```
.service_menu li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 14px;
}
```

... or to be more flexible you can also write:

```
line-height:1em;
```

Comment: Hi mate. thanks for your response. I really do appreciate the help. Adding that to my stylesheet has worked for the most part. However, two pages still have it happening whilst hovering over one or two of the bars or restaurants:           [link] http://www.innexdesign.co.uk/drinking.html, [link]http://innexdesign.co.uk/eating.html. In eating.html it only happens when i hover over one bar:"The Ship". In drinking.html it happens when i hover over "The Penny Bank" and "The Swinging Witch". Any thoughts on why those last couple remain with a wobble whils im hovering over?Thanks agn!

Comment: Well, thats because of the white-space word-wrap. The hovered text (italic + bold) grows and doesn't fit in the single line anymore. Propably you should change the hover style to something which doesn't change the text width, or you can add some pixels to the width of your service_menu.

Comment: Cheers i'll give that a try Philipooo